# On hover get value inside <text></text> element in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented a functionality in which if **user hover's over a pie chart**. I change the **barchart** according to the **pieChart value**.

I am able to get the **fill color** value which is in **path element** as attribute in the **pieChart using DOMElement**. But I am not able to get the **value that is in text element generated by pieChart**. I guess I cant use DOM for it.

How can I get value inside **text element** using javascript or d3JS

My Code

```
var pieHover = function(d,i){

            var DOMelement = this; 
            var fill = DOMelement.getAttribute("fill");
            var countryName = DOMelement.getAttribute("Country");
            console.log("country :"+text);
            console.log(fill);
            chart1.colour(fill);
            chart1.render();
        }


pie1.pieOverCallback(pieHover);
```

What are the different ways to **access data from html elements**?

[image: PieChart with text elements]

below is the hierarchical layout of html file. And I need to access data in `<text>` element.
[image: html layout]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly how your generated HTML/SVG is structured. If `<text>` is a child of `<path>` then you might be able to use `DOMelement.childNodes` or a similar method to get `<text>`, then use `.getAttribute("text")` of the child. Otherwise, you might try grouping both `<path>` and `<text>` inside a `<g>` tag, then you could use `DOMelement.parentNode`.

Comment: Hi, I have added the screenshot, please check. What I am accessing is in svg > g > text. And I tried DOMelement.g.getAttribute("text"); but no luck. I dont know if .getAttribute is a right method to pull data in text element.

Comment: I recommend grouping path/text pairs inside an additional layer of `<g>` elements. Currently, there is no way of systematically knowing which `<text>` to select based on any given `<path>`. If there are only two elements grouped together, then you can easily get the one and only sibling element.